# NeoPixel THT: Varying pinouts

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver, rgb, through-hole

I am in the process of designing a PCB for a solder kit that receives
NeoPixel type LEDs, the ones with the short head:

[image: Short head NeoPixel]

Now, there seem to be different pinouts:

- Ordered on Amazon.de as *WS2811 LED Chip*:

  ```
  (DIN, GND, +5V, DOUT|
  ```

  This pinout I figured out myself. With several batches I got the
  same pinout. (The datasheet for these actually had *different
  pinouts* in *different locations*, and so I fried a few at first.)
- [WS2812D-F5](http://www.world-semi.com/Certifications/details-135-4.html):

  ```
  (DIN, GND, +5V, DOUT|
  ```

  This pinout is in the datasheet [WS2812D-F5-15MA-C1规格
  书_18031509334119.pdf](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/135) available on the Worldsemi’s web site.
- SparkFun [LED - RGB Addressable, PTH, 5mm Clear](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/COM-12877.pdf):

  ```
  (DIN, +5V, GND, DOUT|
  ```

  See the datasheet [COM-12877.pdf](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/COM-12877.pdf) on the SparkFun web site.
- Regular NeoPixels (long head), distributed by Adafruit as
  [NeoPixel Diffused 8mm Through-Hole LED](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1734):

  ```
  (DIN, +5V, GND, DOUT|
  ```

  See the picture [1734-04.jpg](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/970x728/1734-04.jpg) on the Adafruit web site.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this: *Is there any system so
that I can know when ordering which pinout I will get?*

## Update

I did a little bit more digging, which may answer the question. There
seem to be two large manufacturs of the NeoPixel type THT LEDs with
short head:

- *Worldsemi Co. Limited,* making the WS2812D-F5 mentioned above:

  ```
  (DIN, GND, +5V, DOUT|
  ```
- *Shenzhen LED Color Opto electronic Co.ltd,* making the [SK6812D5](http://www.szledcolor.com/productshow.asp?id=968&sid=199)
  ([datasheet](http://www.szledcolor.com/download/SK6812%20F5.pdf)) and the [APA106](http://www.szledcolor.com/productshow.asp?id=891&sid=199):

  ```
  (DIN, +5V, GND, DOUT|
  ```

My take is that it’s best to order from vendors that clearly state the
model number. Interesting is also the WikiLEDia [list of chips](https://wikiledia.net/index.php?title=Chips)
sorted by manufacturer.

Comment: If you want consistency you have to buy from actual distributors, not random deal importers.  This questionnis off-topic here.

Comment: As said, the system applies to components just as well as it applies to cars, houses, fruit, meat, shoes and drugs: Reputable sellers will provide you with goods with a specification that actually applies. Other sellers shouldn't be getting your money. Full stop. I have zero sympathies for people getting scammed on aliexpress, amazon marketplace, or banggood.

Comment: @MarcusMüller nobody got scammed